# Seeking process in ModelBuilder that can choose among several shapefiles in folder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I created a model in **ArcGIS 10** which selects those parcels that intersect my polygon shapefile.

It will then remove all r.o.w parcels.

I then export the table it produces to an excel file. The shapefiles are in a folder.

Is there a process which will direct ModelBuilder to said folder then prompt me as to which shapefile I want to run without using python?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **(Iterate Files)** and it gives you the ability also to define (Name, or part of the names of your feature to be iterate over them)

[image]

For example names of features start with D (D*)

Also, you can define the file extension such as (.shp) for just the shapefiles

[image]

[Iterate Files Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-files.htm)

[Iterate Files example](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/examples-of-using-iterators-in-modelbuilder.htm)

Also, the modelBuilder only tools are useful, more information in this [link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/a-quick-tour-of-using-model-only-tools.htm)

**Updated Answer (according to the comments below)**

If you would add your data folder in the ModelBuilder, and using (Select data) tool, you can have the ability to get all the files in the folder.

But in this case, you should manually choose the feature that you would work on further in the model.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.  however, after running your model i'm not asked which shp I want to run. maybe modelbuilder can't do that.  do I need to write a python script?  I also don't know how to connect your model to mine.

Comment: @jwag Of course the ModelBuilder will not ask you which shape you want to run, you need to define which shapefiles (by type, by part of the name or by name). In other words (the model will search over all your files for the defined shapefile and give it to you as output for further processing). Regarding connect my model to yours, I didn't understand what do you mean?

Comment: I always suspected modelbuilder won't ask which shapefile you want to run but my supervisor thought it did.  so that's why i was asking.

Comment: according to my supervisor modelbuilder can open your folder that contains the shapefiles.  then you just select whichever shapefile you want and modelbuilder will run it. sound plausible?

Comment: @jwag I updated my answer, please check it and toggled it as accepted if it helps you.

Comment: if you go to this link you'll see the model tool dialog box that we want to see when we run the model. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/creating-model-parameter.htm

Comment: @jwag what's the relation of what's in the link and your question (your needs). Please always be clear when describing your problem and what you want to achieve so we can help you to solve this problem without being dispersed many times.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I totally understand the question, but the iterate tools within modelbuilder might be what you're looking for. You input a specified folder and it will run the model for each feature within the folder.